# How to make local DNS for pointing domain *.local to localhost?

Tags: windows-7, dns, xampp, hosts-file, development

I'm developing websites and I use xampp which is configured to automaticly point some type of domains to xampp main directory. For example: When I go to `site1.local` xampp is displaying page located at `<xampp_projects_direcory>/site1/`. If I go to `wewqeqwje.local` it will automaticly search directory `wewqeqwje` and so on.

But now I need to add every domain name to `hosts` file for every new project.

It is possible to automatize process of adding domains to hosts or maybe installing some software pointing all ***.local** to 127.0.0.1?

I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You could use localtest.me, an online service that is designed to specifically address this problem:
http://readme.localtest.me/

Comment: It is interesting and works, but without internet connection it fails. I found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/138162/269804